# How to change sortable element's style while dragging?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Here is my script:

```
<script>
    $(function() {
    t1 = window.performance.now()
    var $sortable1 = $( "#dragableElement" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
      items: ".sorting-initialize",
      containment: "window"

    });
    $sortable1.find(".ui-state-default").one("mouseenter",function(){
        $(this).addClass("sorting-initialize");
        $sortable1.sortable('refresh');

    });

    t2 = window.performance.now()
    console.log(t2-t1)
  });
  </script>
```

Is it possible to change styling of dragged item in this script? For example add background : 'yellow' and it changes color and etc.?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can also use jQueryUi sortable events [start](https://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-start) for this try this:-

```
 $( "#dragableElement" ).sortable({
    connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
    items: ".sorting-initialize",
    containment: "window",
    start: function( event, ui ) { 
      $(ui.item).addClass("yellow");
    },
    stop:function( event, ui ) { 
      $(ui.item).removeClass("yellow");
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UAcC7/1504/)

Comment: When i add those start and stop functions to my code, drag and drop is gone. Any idea why? When i comment these lines, everything works great.

Comment: and make sure you have `,` after `containment: "window"` it should be `containment: "window",`

Comment: Yeah i missed "," after "window", but still, when i use drag and drop style doesn't change no matter which color is selected.

Comment: did you add class `yellow`  to css?

Comment: `.yellow
{
    background:yellow;
}`

Answer (score 5):

When you sort an item, a class `ui-sortable-helper` is added to the item. You can use this class to change the appearance of the item being sorted. You can then use CSS rules to alter the appearance of this item. However, you have to ensure that your css overrides the default css of jQuery UI. For that, you may need to have very specific selectors.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/UAcC7/1503/

CSS:

```
.ui-sortable-helper {
    background:green;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="demo">
        <ul id="sortable">
            <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 1</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 2</li>
            <li class="ui-state-default"><span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-2-n-s"></span>Item 7</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- End demo -->
    <div class="demo-description" style="display: none; ">
        <p>Enable a group of DOM elements to be sortable. Click on and drag an element to a new spot within the list, and the other items will adjust to fit. By default, sortable items share <code>draggable</code> properties.</p>
    </div>
    <!-- End demo-description -->
```

JS:

```
$("#sortable").sortable();
```